# Connect HANA Express with MySQL via Smart Data Access

Tags: mysql, odbc, driver, hana, unixodbc

I need to connect my HANA Express VM with a MySQL database. What I did so far is:

0.) Registered VM and installed unixODBC (as described in Youtube Playlist)

1.) Downloaded ODBC driver installation files (rpm)

2.) sudo zypper install

3.) myodbc-installer -d -l

4.) cp /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini

5.) cp /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini

6.) nano ~/.odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
ds2 = myodbc5w
ds1 = myodbc5a
Default = Default

[myodbc5w]
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5w.so
DATABASE        = <sqldb>
DESCRIPTION     = MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver test
SERVER          = <sqlip>
UID             = <sqluser>
USER            = <sqluser>
PASSWORD        = <pw>

[myodbc5a]
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so
DATABASE        = <sqldb>
DESCRIPTION     = MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver test
SERVER          = <sqlip>
UID             = <sqluser>
USER            = <sqluser>
PASSWORD        = <pw>

[Default]
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so
DATABASE        = <sqldb>
DESCRIPTION     = MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver test
SERVER          = <sqlip>
UID             = <sqluser>
USER            = <sqluser>
PASSWORD        = <pw>
```

7.) nano ~/.odbcinst.ini

```
[MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5w.so
UsageCount=1

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so
UsageCount=1

[Default]
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so
UsageCount=1
```

8.) nano ~/.customer.sh

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64
export ODBCINI=$HOME/.odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=$HOME
```

9.) Restarted VM

10.) I can successfully connect by calling

```
isql myodbc5w <user> <pw>
```

11.) Also this call works

```
myodbc-installer -d -l

MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
Default
```

**Now my problem and questions:**

Why won't also my Smart Data Access access the MySQL (it seems to connect, but can't list the tables)? And what shall I set the "Configuration File" property with? And what's wrong with the odbc / odbcinst files, that only "Default" works?

I adapted the odbc file from an example which was shipped with the ODBC installation...

See screenshot for my SDA settings (only "Default" data source worked for me yet).

[image]

I'm working for days now on this problem, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If SDI is also an option for you, you could try to connect via DP-Agent and CamelJdbcAdapter or the MySQL Adapter from github, check https://help.sap.com/viewer/7952ef28a6914997abc01745fef1b607/1.0_SPS12/en-US/6ed502701abd4d1ca94d463d7dc6e99f.html or  https://github.com/SAP/hana-native-adapters?files=1. depending on your release

Comment: The problem lies with the MySQL driver as it doesn't expose the required database catalog information. Use one of @ChristophG 's alternatives.

Comment: So, I can't use the ODBC driver of MySQL, right? Which alternative can I use to connect my SAP HANA Express 2.0 SP01 with my MySQL db? All guides I found yet seem to work for HANA 1.x instances.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue. I installed mariadb connector (not MySQL connector):
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/

```
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.1.7/mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz
cp lib/libmaodbc.so /lib64/
```

Next, i made an entry for Maria in .odbc.ini

```
[Maria]
Description = MariaDB 3.1.7 ODBC
Driver = /lib64/libmaodbc.so
SERVER = <your server>
```

and then:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i011j.jpg)